# What is this strut in biplane rigging, attached only to wires, not bearing any load?

Tags: aircraft-design, feature-identification, biplane

A few biplanes like the Stearman have a strut parallel to the fuselage, halfway along the rigging's landing wires and flying wires, not fastened to the airframe, *not bearing any obvious load*.  One on each side.  What are they for?  What are they called?

I'd guess that because some of the Stearman's wires are doubled (also unusual?), the strut prevents them from banging into each other and chafing.  But that seems unlikely because their tension is 800 to 1400 pounds, according to page 24 of the Dec. 2007 issue of [Vintage Airplane](http://members.eaavintage.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/VA-Vol-35-No-12-Dec-2007.pdf) (p. 26 of the pdf).  Even if a maneuver temporarily halved that tension, deflecting one of those by two inches to hit its twin would take tons of force.

[image: Boeing Stearman]
(image source: [Wikimedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNhRV.jpg))

Comment: One might imagine the strut helps control fluttering of the cables at certain airspeeds.  The "buzz" would be (at least) very annoying, and could possibly compromise any attached fittings (due to vibration).

Comment: It's a handle for the wing-walker.

Comment: I think it's called a javelin.

Comment: @Flynn That's descriptive, and likely.  There's a 1963 EAA reference to "javelin struts" taped(!) to the flying and landing wires of a Waco 9 biplane to reduce "flutter."  Worth an answer in itself.

Comment: hah.  If you played the 'cello you'd know in an instant  :-) .  We have similar gadgets called "wolf eliminators" which do the same job:  kill off unwanted resonances.

Comment: I strongly suggest (on all sites) when there's an error in the title, just edit it

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's just a stick set between the flying and landing wires (the "wires" are actually solid stainless steel rods with an almond cross section for streamlining - they are VERY expensive).  Normally they are made from wooden dowel with notches for the wires to fit, retained in the notches by wraps of lockwire, or on fancier biplanes they may be made from aluminum tube with a bullet nose and pointed tail.

They are usually called "wire stays". Their main function is to stop the wires from vibrating in the airflow (they're more or less metal vocal cords), which can create a lot of noise (that's the traditional diving airplane sound effect from the movies, as you can hear hear [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DFFYHPbG9A&t=1h50m30s), at 1:50:30, in Hell's Angels, one of the earliest sound movies with airplanes). The noise is from the "Wind in the Wires" (the title of a book by WWI pilot [Duncan Grinnell-Milne](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10344490-wind-in-the-wires)). More importantly, the vibration can also induce fatigue cracking of the streamlined rods over the long term. Linking them together changes the natural frequency of the wires to something much higher than an individual wire, and stops them from vibrating in the airplane's speed range.

Comment: Yes, I see how such a stick raises the resonant frequency.  (1) Am I just inattentive to not see it on other biplanes, with similar rigging?  Why not on those as well?  (2) I found a few pre-WWI references to wire stays on airplanes, but it wasn't clear that the term meant these sticks.  Any references for this term?  (fyi "wire stay" in common sailing parlance means a forestay or backstay made of wire instead of solid rod, hemp, etc.;  that's what it sounded like in what I found, the "flying wires" were themselves called "wire stays.")

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune made my own revisions and additions based on your edit suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune I would say they are pretty common on biplanes.  I see them more often than not. Like here: https://buildandfly.shop/product/pitts-s1s/ .   They are actually quite important to prevent fatigue cracking at the threads of streamline sold rod wires. The term is one I recall from my own experience around homebuilts over the years and I guess the meaning has changed somewhat in the adoption from the nautical.  I looked around on the web and has a surprisingly hard time finding any direct references.

Comment: Edited to remove the parenthetical about the diving airplane's sound effect being from vibrating cables. That particular sound is actually from the [Junkers Ju-87 "Stuka"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_Ju_87) dive bomber, which used a siren to try and scare civilians. Every other time a diving airplane has made that sound, it's because some [Foley artist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foley_(filmmaking)) thought that diving planes should make that sound, so they added it in post-production.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield  Your edit is wrong. The Stuka's siren is quite different from wire howling and diving airplanes making a howl due to the wires was part of the public consciousness in the 30s as soon as sound film involving airplanes came out. I've restored my edit with a link to an early movie, Hell's Angels, that predates the Stuka's entry into the public consciousness by about 6 or 7 years at least.   I've restored the part you took out with a link to the movie.

Comment: Like that old folk song about a plane crash said-- "the wind in the wires made a tattletale sound"...

Comment: Yeah actually I think HW had it backwards. Junkers put the siren on to imitate and magnify the sound that diving biplanes made, because that sound was already associated with "death from above".

Comment: @JohnK Do you have a source for that? I've heard plenty of biplanes, and have never heard them make any sound that's anywhere close to a "Stuka Scream". I also can't find any reference to the sirens being developed because of existing sounds that biplanes made.

Comment: Something I read many years ago in a magazine,  Don't have a reference. In any case,some foley artists may have used Stuka recordings for their effects, but as I showed, it predates the Stuka, like Hell's Angels", where they were adding the noise long before the Stuka was around.  For the real deal, watch this clip of Dawn Patrol at 1:36 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eSvpeIaMRI  The film recorded the aircraft flying by and you can actually hear the howl from the wires.  Read accounts of WWI combat pilots, like the author I linked to, and references to screaming wires is common.

Comment: I have a memory about empty bottles being thrown from planes in WW1 because they whistled like falling bombs and kept AA gunners in their bunkers.  Though this might have been in a Biggles book.